How to handle access_token from query, set it in cookies, and remove it from URL in Nuxt.js 2 middleware?
I'm using Nuxt.js 2 in server rendering mode and I have two middlewares in the following order:
auth: This middleware retrieves cookies from the server and stores user info in Vuex.
publicRouteCheck: This middleware checks if the current route requires user authentication based on a list of public routes.
Now, I'm receiving my access_token in the query parameters, and I need to:
Retrieve the access_token from the query string.
Call an API with the access_token to get user information.
Set the access_token in the cookies.
Remove the access_token from the URL.
Proceed with the remaining middlewares.
I'm not sure how to implement this. Here's what I have so far:
auth: middleware
        const token = $cookies.get(TOKEN_KEY) || route.query?.token;
        if (token && !store.getters.getUser) {
            const userInfoData =
                await $repositories.VuiHocRepository.getUserProfile();            
            if (userInfoData?.success) {
                store.commit("SET_USER", userInfoData.data);                
            }
        }
        if (route.query?.token) {
            console.log('client');
            const query = _.cloneDeep(route?.query);
            const accessToken = query?.token;
            if (accessToken) {
                $cookies.set("access_token", accessToken, {
                    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1,
                    path: "/",
                    secure: true,
                });
                delete query.token;
            }
    
            redirect({...route, query});
        }

private-page:
const publicRoutesName = [
        '/abc'
    ];
    const user = store.getters.getUser;
    if (!user && route.name && !publicRoutesName.includes(route.name)) {
        return redirect("/");
    }

I initially tried to handle the access_token directly within my existing auth middleware by parsing the query parameters and then making an API call to fetch user info. However, I faced issues with properly setting cookies both on the server and client sides, and I couldn't cleanly remove the token from the URL without disrupting the navigation flow.
